# Calling for action: Help improving our tag wikis

Tags: support, tags

Some of our tag wikis need to be improved, and they need the help of the community. Before to describe the task, I will give a description of what a tag wiki is.

Each tag, such as [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views), has [a page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/views/info) associated with it, which describes the tag, and it is split between its excerpt and the tag wiki itself.

- The excerpt gives a short description about the tag, or the purpose of the tag; it's what the users see when hovering a tag used by a question, and when choosing a tag while editing a question.

  [image: screenshot]

  [image: screenshot]
- The tag wiki itself, which can be a longer text, and can contain links, normally describes in more details what the purpose of the tag is.

  - If the tag is about a Drupal module, then it contains a link to the project page hosted on Drupal.org; this is particularly useful when there are similar modules with similar names.
  - If there are tags for which the users could get confused about which one to use, and when, the tag wiki should give a list of such tags, and explain what the difference between the currently explained tag and those tags is.
  - If there are particular important questions, which are also great examples of questions using the tag, the tag wiki should report a list of those questions, possibly avoiding to add too much questions in the list.

The task is to improve the tag wikis to include the information I reported before. For the excerpt you can notice that some of them start with, "Topics" or "Questions"; that part can generally be removed, and the excerpt rewritten. For example, the excerpt for [pathauto](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathauto) was the following one:

> Topics about PathAuto, the third-party module that allows to automatically create path aliases for different type of pages.

Re-editing it to remove *Topics*, it becomes:

> PathAuto is a module that allows to automatically create path aliases for different type of pages.

Consider also adding the links to the project pages, when the tag wiki refers a module. Only the tag wiki can contain links, as its excerpt is plain text, and it cannot use any Markdown markup.

The following are some tips:

- Not all the information I reported before are strictly necessary, except the description for the purpose of the tag. If there aren't tags too similar to the one described in the tag wiki, then the part about similar tags can be omitted; if there aren't great questions using that tag (which also means with high votes), the list of questions using that tag can be omitted.
- Editing only the excerpt is fine, as long as the edit is not, e.g., adding a punctuation mark; it is not necessary to edit both the excerpt, and the tag wiki.
- Editing tag wikis doesn't cause any question bump; this means that it can be done at any time. I would rather suggest not to do too much edits during a day; it must not be a rush to edit the most number of tag wikis.
- When choosing which tag wikis should be edited, choose the ones with most questions using them; the [page that lists the existing tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags) already shows them from the most used ones to the less used ones. Avoid editing a tag wiki when the tag is used from less than 10 questions.
- Give the priority to editing the existing tag wikis. There could be tags without a tag wiki, but not all the tags need one.

What do you gain in helping with this task? All users but 20k users and moderators get 2 points for every approved edit on tag wikis. There is a limit of 1000 points every user can gain on suggested edits, and the limit includes the tag wiki edits; 1000 points is the maximum every user can gain with suggested edits.
For who edits 50 tag wikis there is also a silver badge: [Research Assistant](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/badges/87/research-assistant).

Comment: This is a good idea, I'll get some done over the next week or so

Comment: Same; kudos for helping to organize this.