# Do we want questions about books and tutorials on DA?

Tags: discussion

So, I was just reading recent questions and ran across: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24381/any-good-books-tutorials-on-drupal-for-an-advanced-php-developer

This is a near duplicate for a few other questions ( https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16922/where-can-i-find-tutorials-about-drupal-or-e-books, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6050/what-is-a-good-book-for-learning-how-to-develop-drupal-7-modules , and likely others), though this one is framed a little differently.

If this wasn't a new DA user, I would vote to close this as not being constructive as all answer could be considered correct.  Also, several of the booklist questions are those involved in the current brouhaha on the main Meta site.

Personally, I don't think these are really good questions, primarily because the answers aren't timeless.  Though programming languages do change over time, the good references still stand.

Drupal however does change, and API changes do mean that some books and tutorials are flat out wrong.  Most of the examples in K&R 2 that show use of stdlib functions are still correct and will work, but many of the examples in the first and second editions of Pro Drupal Development will result in problems because the API has changed.

So, what should be done with these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What can be done is to close those questions as not constructive, as that closing reason includes the following sentence:

> We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise.

To answer those questions there is not need to have a specific expertise, the answers don't normally involve references, or facts.
See [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16997/199) given for https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16922/where-can-i-find-tutorials-about-drupal-or-e-books

> Lullabot video tutorials are worst.
>
> The best are: 1) From Lynda.com 2) Buildamodule.com (Chris Chaddick)
>
> For e-books check their reviews.

The answer doesn't have any reference, and it is not reporting facts, but rather opinions.

Those list type questions should be updated all the times a new tutorial is created, or every time a new Drupal major version is created. For this, there isn't a definitive answer.

If it is necessary (which means if the question could be helpful for future readers), a question could be created merging the existing questions. I rather think that a list of tutorials can be added to the tag wikis every tag has, and which are used also for listing useful resources associated with the tag. For example, in the tag wiki for [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) you could add a list of tutorials about creating a view, or using the Views module.
See [Calling for action: Help improving our tag wikis](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/741/calling-for-action-help-improving-our-tag-wikis) for more information.

Comment: Do mods see lists of questions w/ close votes, or do things like this also need to be flagged?

Comment: 10k users see the questions that have been voted to be closed; that include moderators, who are considered as 20k users with more privileges (whatever their actual reputation is). If you vote to close, that is enough.